# Getting a Chrome app window to open at the bottom right of screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I would like my Chrome app to open so it's touching the task bar and just offset from the right of the screen.

My current code:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 325
    },
    'resizable': false,
    frame: 'none'
  });      
});
```

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript.

Comment: @Xan I know. I'm looking for some help.

Comment: What kind of help you need and will be useful depends on your current level of knowledge. So far, not great. Can you at least make some code that runs, even if it does not do what you want? I mean, this code is one big syntax error.

Comment: @xan My knowledge is limited. I cut out the code that had issue. This loads my extension in the center of the screen.

Comment: Edited your question a bit. Note: chrome apps are not the same as extensions; fixed the title and tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with setting the **outer** bounds, that is, the full window size (and the content is potentially smaller), then it's simple:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  var windowWidth = 300;
  var windowHeight = 325;
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    outerBounds: { // 'bounds' is deprecated, and you want full window size
      width: windowWidth,
      height: windowHeight,
      left: screen.availWidth - windowWidth,
      top: screen.availHeight - windowHeight,
    },
    resizable: false,
    frame: 'none'
  });      
});
```

If you want to set **inner** bounds, that is the exact size of the window content, then you can't predict the size of the window accurately. You'll have to first create it and then reposition it in the callback:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  var windowWidth = 300;
  var windowHeight = 325;
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'window.html',
    {
      innerBounds: {
        width: windowWidth,
        height: windowHeight
      },
      resizable: false,
      frame: 'none'
    },
    function(win) {
      win.outerBounds.setPosition(
        screen.availWidth - win.outerBounds.width, // left
        screen.availHeight - win.outerBounds.height // top
      );
    }
  );      
});
```

All in all, it'a a good idea to review the actual documentation of [`chrome.app.window` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window).