# Make Chrome Extension Window Resizeable and Pop Out of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie when it comes to Chrome Extension development, so I really am struggling with this.  I'm trying to build an extension where the popout is resizable by the user and can be dragged anywhere without limits.  Existing extensions that do this today that I know of are Jungle Scout and AMZ Scout, so I know it can be done.

Someone tried doing this at this StackOverflow link a few years ago but I couldn't get it to work: [Getting a Chrome app window to open at the bottom right of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224923/getting-a-chrome-app-window-to-open-at-the-bottom-right-of-screen)

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe it's actually a popup window opened when you press the button, not an addon bubble? I'm not sure (on mobile)

Comment: You can't move the standard extension popup which means those extensions use something else so your first step should be to use devtools and find out what that is. You'll find one of the two available options: a DOM element in the active page, or a separate window opened via chrome.windows.create.