# Fixed and always on top popup window in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, popupwindow

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension and I need to make a popup window that is fixed in a corner and always on top of the other windows.

I leave a reference image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I am finding your image hard to interpret, please add additional explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MandyShaw thanks for the welcome. 
I am develop a small extension for chrome, which consists of a pop up window https://imgur.com/a/eTafnyJ. I want to know how I can do that window without using window.open and leave it fixed in the lower right corner. It's the same as the open in floating for youtube extension but I just need to open an iframe

Answer (score 11):

#### Bad news...

I'm sorry but it's not possible anymore to force a window to stay always on top. However, if you only need to open a window in the bottom-right corner of the screen, take a look at this other answer: [Getting a Chrome app window to open at the bottom right of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224923/getting-a-chrome-app-window-to-open-at-the-bottom-right-of-screen).

Before, one option was to use [`chrome.windows.create({ type: 'panel' })`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create). Panels could have any size and position, supported the always on top functionality, could display any arbitrary piece of code... **But they are gone now**, as you can see on the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowType):

> `"panel"`
>
> *Deprecated in this API.* A Chrome App panel-style window. Extensions can only see their own panel windows.

The main reason for the removal was that it's too expensive to maintain, as you can read in [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/10/19/google-removes-panel-support-from-chrome/).

Another option used to be [`webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications), **but that one is gone too**:

> **Warning:** `webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification()` in the [web notifications API](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) has been deprecated. The [new web notifications API](https://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) only allows text. [Chrome notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) will be promoted to stable soon and web notifications will be updated to use the new rich notifications format.

You are not alone though. A lot of extension like [Always On Top for YouTube™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-on-top-for-youtube/mhlhpnnkggabcgkpblgcljghnmjjnkfl) or [Picture in Picture Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-viewer/efaagmolahogmekmnmkigonhfcdiemnl) relied on the always on top functionality and you can see from the bad reviews that they haven't been able or willing to find alternative solutions.

#### Alternative for images

One alternative to display only images (might not work for you as you probably need sound as well) would be to use an [image notification](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-TemplateType) with a canvas image that you can generate and update dynamically from a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

With this approach, you might be able to display animations/videos, but I'm not sure how smooth it would be.

#### Alternative using context scripts

If you want to permanently display any arbitrary code to the user, you could use the [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to keep track of the active tab and insert custom code on it using [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) and [`insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS).

The three main drawbacks of this approach are that:

- The content won't appear instantly, especially in the case of videos which need to load first, so when users switch tabs, they will actually notice how the injected content appears again and loads whatever it has to load.
- If Chrome is minimized or partially off-screen, they might not see the injected content.
- Conflicts with existing code on the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. Use the windows.create function windows.create and add a test iframe and add the permissions to the manifest.json but when opening the extension it tells me the following error "an extension blocked the requests to the server"

Window error: https://imgur.com/SWGqVEB
Manifest.json: https://imgur.com/iqJ9Kgb

Comment: You might be missing the [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) property in your manifest. It should be an array that includes the HTML file you are loading on that iframe, as well as any other CSS, JS or image that HTML file is loading.