# Chrome creating a borderless window and keeping it on top of other windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I m working on a chrome extension where I need to show a window like this one, which remains always on top of other windows. Is there any chrome helper method for creating this?

[image]

Comment: No, extensions can't do it. You can write an external utility and call it via `nativeMessaging`.

Comment: Also [Fixed and always on top popup window in a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53052888)